# Hiding a Pandas data frame index causes the rows to re-order

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote the following which I'm using to display "all possible choices" for three objects of three types:

```
import pandas as pd
types_table = pd.DataFrame({1:[], 2:[], 3:[]})
c1 = [1+round(x // 9) for x in range(27)]
c2 = [1+(round(x//3) % 3) for x in range(27)]
c3 = [1+(x % 3) for x in range(27)]
types_table[1]=c1
types_table[2]=c2
types_table[3]=c3
print(types_table.to_string(index=False))
```

The code basically works, but the `index=False` bit causes the rows to re-order in an unhelpful way.  Whereas if I leave it as just `print(types_table)` it looks perfect except the indices cause some visual clutter.  Does anyone know how to resolve both issues simultaneously?  If I try to first perform a sort on the data, then I still have to call `to_string` at the end with `index=False` and it'll just again re-order the data.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any row re-arrangement on my system. What do you mean it reorder the data?

Comment: @QuangHoang On my system, the first row becomes `1 2 3` whereas it should be `1 1 1`.  When called without the `to_string(index=False)` the first row displays as `1 1 1` as desired.

Comment: this first row `1 2 3` you see are the column names

Comment: @Stef Ah, I see it removed the formatting that indicated column titles.  Then follow-up question: Is there a way to put the column headers back on?

Comment: `print(types_table.to_string(index=False, header=False))` removes that first label row.